# porque el left join no da lo mismo que el right join

Tags: sql

me gustaría que me ayudaran por favor a entender porque la primera consulta da totalmente diferente a la segunda:
Primera consulta:

```
SELECT campos
from Tabla1
left join tabla2
ON tabla2.clave = Tabla1.Clave
inner join Tabla3 
on Tabla3.Clave = tabla2.clave
INNER JOIN Tabla4
ON Tabla3.clave = Tabla4.Clave
```

Segunda consulta:

```
SELECT campos
FROM     Tabla3 
INNER JOIN Tabla2 
ON Tabla3.Clave = Tabla2.clave 
INNER JOIN Tabla4 
ON Tabla3.clave = Tabla4.Clave 
RIGHT JOIN Tabla1 
ON Tabla2.clave = Tabla1.Clave
```

el objetivo es traer toooda la información de la tabla1 sin importar que cruce con las otras tablas, pero porque la segunda consulta si funciona y la primera no.

les agradezco la aclaración.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. A la pregunta quizá le falta un poco más de escenario. Puedes darle a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: @Javifer2 evita la autopromocion...podrias agregar una respuesta completa y ahi si hacer referencia..

Answer (score 1):

El problema de la primer consulta, es que primero está haciendo el `LEFT JOIN` y después está realizando los `INNER JOIN`. Por lo tanto, el `LEFT JOIN` está siendo tratado como un `INNER JOIN`. Para poder obtener la funcionalidad deseada, lo que se requiere es aplicar una sintaxis que puede ser un poco confusa, pero podría ser más claro con paréntesis. Lo que se indica es que primero se realicen los `INNER JOIN` y después el `LEFT JOIN`.

Dejo un ejemplo con datos de prueba para poder ver claramente la funcionalidad. Los paréntesis son completamente opcionales en este caso, pero están para dar un poco de claridad a lo que se hace.

```
CREATE TABLE Tabla1( Clave1 int) INSERT INTO Tabla1 VALUES(1), (2), (3)
CREATE TABLE Tabla2( Clave2 int, Clave1 int) INSERT INTO Tabla2 VALUES(1,1), (2,1), (3,2)
CREATE TABLE Tabla3( Clave3 int, Clave2 int) INSERT INTO Tabla3 VALUES(1,1), (2,1), (3,2)
CREATE TABLE Tabla4( Clave4 int, Clave3 int) INSERT INTO Tabla4 VALUES(1,1), (2,1), (3,2)

SELECT *
from Tabla1
left join (tabla2  
inner join Tabla3 on Tabla3.Clave2 = tabla2.Clave2
INNER JOIN Tabla4 ON Tabla3.Clave3 = Tabla4.Clave3) ON tabla2.clave1 = Tabla1.Clave1


SELECT *
FROM       Tabla3 
INNER JOIN Tabla2 ON Tabla3.Clave2 = Tabla2.Clave2 
INNER JOIN Tabla4 ON Tabla3.clave3 = Tabla4.Clave3 
RIGHT JOIN Tabla1 ON Tabla2.clave2 = Tabla1.Clave1
```

Answer (score 0):

Left Join significa que la consulta te devolverá todos los campos de la tabla 1 y solo aquellos de la tabla 2 que sean iguales, en el resto será Null. Rigth join lo mismo pero te devuelve todos los campos de la tabla 2. Inner join devuelve aquellos campos que en ambas tablas son iguales. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Hola Luis te agradezco la respuesta y te comprendo lo que me quieres compartir, pero imagínate que el left join que tengo al principio no me trae todos los datos datos de la tabla1, es como si los inner join de abajo afectaran el left.